# In where condition use column value which contains column name

Tags: sql-server

I have below table. let table name =Emp

[image: Emp table]

I need to query in the table like below.

```
select * from Emp
where [*]
```

`[*]` <- Here instead of writing country='India', I want to use the column business_rule directly so that i can get the records

Business rule column in not a consistent one. I have given two columns as example. But it may contain 2, 3 or more column names under business_rule

Comment: search _dynamic SQL_. but this is a bad idea. if rules are always of that form, you could have `business_rule_name` and `business_rule_country` columns with the required values and compare to those. you shouldn't need dynamic SQL at all.

Comment: That's a great way to get hacked - someone could write `1=1; drop table Emp;--` and drop the table directly

Comment: You'll have to do this dynamically in a procedure. You can't dynamically reference a database object (database, schema, table, column, etc) in a sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

As everybody is answering you, to do this you'll need [dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/).

This is a simple dynamic SQL comparison:

**T-SQL**

```
'SELECT * FROM production.products';
```

**Dynamic SQL**

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM production.products';
```

This often is a bad idea/practice because some users could [SQL inject](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-injection-what-is-it-causes-and-exploits/) your database.